Flag to close dialog is positioned too far to the right and down
If you want to flag to close a question, the second dialog which provides the global close reasons is positioned too far to the right and down. I might even need to scroll a bit (depending on the zoom level; the new font is a bit thin) to see the flag button.

Both dialogs have roughly the same width, but the second one is not centered for some reason.
Browser: Firefox 43.0.1
Yay! Gif!

Thanks for reporting! This will be fixed today.

Hi @Paweł, it seems all current [meta-tag:status-planned] are now [meta-tag:status-completed]. Thanks!

Not all, but this one yes :)
